# Python matplotlib - unalphabetize a graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am taking data from a spreadsheet and trying to graph everything but whenever I put the data into a graph, my graph gets alphabetized.
[image]

But the list I feed into it looks like:

```
['Apr 2016', 'May 2016', 'Jun 2016', 'Jul 2016', 'Aug 2016', 'Sep 2016', 
'Oct 2016', 'Nov 2016', 'Dec 2016', 'Jan 2017', 'Feb 2017', 'Mar 2017', 
'Apr 2017', 'May 2017', 'Jun 2017', 'Jul 2017', 'Aug 2017', 'Sep 2017', 
'Oct 2017']
```

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sheet = pd.ExcelFile("path to spreadsheet").parse()


def graph_column(category_name, exel_sheet):

    plt.xlabel("Month")
    plt.ylabel("Dollars")
    plt.title(category_name)

    month_list = []
    row_list = []

    for row in range(len(exel_sheet["Monthly Sales"])):
        month = exel_sheet["Monthly Sales"][row]
        month_list.append(month)
        row = float(exel_sheet[category_name][row])
        row_list.append(row)

    print(month_list)
    plt.barh(month_list, row_list)
    plt.show()


graph_column("Grocery", sheet)
```

How can I make it so the graph isnt sorted alphabetically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The barplot thinks your dates are categories. While one option may of course be to convert them into real dates (`datetime` objects) a potentially simpler solution in this case is to plot the bars in terms of integer values and set the labels accordingly.

```
plt.barh(range(len(row_list)), row_list)
plt.yticks(range(len(row_list)), month_list)
```

It might then make sense to invert the y scale via `plt.gca().invert_yaxis()`.